# Converting the command line python code to normal python script without command line

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, streamlit

**I have the following code which takes input from the command line. I want to run this code in streamlit and not take the values of the arguments from the command line, instead set them to some default values like for '-i', I want it by default to open the camera. How can I achieve this?**

```
def build_argparser():
    parser = ArgumentParser()

    general = parser.add_argument_group('General')
    general.add_argument('-i', '--input', metavar="PATH", default='0',
                         help="(optional) Path to the input video " \
                         "('0' for the camera, default)")
    general.add_argument('-o', '--output', metavar="PATH", default="",
                         help="(optional) Path to save the output video to")
    general.add_argument('--no_show', action='store_true',
                         help="(optional) Do not display output")
    general.add_argument('-tl', '--timelapse', action='store_true',
                         help="(optional) Auto-pause after each frame")
    general.add_argument('-cw', '--crop_width', default=0, type=int,
                         help="(optional) Crop the input stream to this width " \
                         "(default: no crop). Both -cw and -ch parameters " \
                         "should be specified to use crop.")
    general.add_argument('-ch', '--crop_height', default=0, type=int,
                         help="(optional) Crop the input stream to this height " \
                         "(default: no crop). Both -cw and -ch parameters " \
                         "should be specified to use crop.")
    general.add_argument('--match_algo', default='HUNGARIAN', choices=MATCH_ALGO,
                         help="(optional)algorithm for face matching(default: %(default)s)")
```

Comment: do you only want to run the script with script name and nothing else or you want to specify the flags while running the script and want these flags run some operation by default?

Comment: I don't want to specify the flags while running the script. I want to set all the flags by default.

Comment: if you don't want any command line arguments then don't use any. Simply, define all the paths and references inside the script.Also, if you are working with camera then have a look at the opencv library which helps you run and make changes to the video frames.

Answer (score 2):

See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-parse-args-method

Normally what we do is this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
# ... define what to expect
arg = parser.parse_args()
```

and `arg` will be the argument object, which is parsed from `sys.argv`, which is what you entered in command line. You can also put the list of strings into the function, such as

```
arg = parser.parse_args(["--match_algo", "-ch"])
```

The link above have more examples for different variations of the arguments you may use.